# Family Tree Visualization

Tags: animation, charts, visualization, interactive

So my father came to me and asked me to create a program that displays my family tree. The names are preset but he wants a visualisation like the following: The root node would be the first ancestor and if you click on that name, the program should then dropdown the next generation originating from that node. He wants this done for each member of the tree to make it interactive. Now obviously computer scientists aren't well versed in such things but I was hoping if anyone could direct me to tools/ builders/ languages I could use to create such an animation no matter how many generations I enter in the tree.

Any tips would be much appreciated. I have never personally dabbled with such kind of animation and visualisations. Thank you!

I tried using services like Creately and LucidChart but they all provided static visualisations. I wasn't able to get each node to produce an animation. I tried to use Netbeans as I know you can create windows with animated buttons but this didn't quite fuflil my father's wish of an aesthetic tree where the arrows drop down nicely and one can simply scroll through it.

Comment: If it *really* is tree, then a structure of folders on the HDD could help...